# Using XNA for a 2D isometric game, but wanna move on

Tags: xna, c++, c#

I've been building a 2D isometric game (with learning purposes) in C# using XNA.

I found it's really easy to manage sprite sheets loading, collision, basic physics and such with the XNA api.

The thing is, I want to move on.

My real goal is to learn C++ and develop a game using that language.

What engine/library would you guys recommend for me to keep going on that same 2D isometric game direction using pretty much sprite sheets for the graphical part of the game?

Comment: Please see the [FAQ] about "which technology to use" and "where to get started" questions.

Answer (score 3):

SDL, It´s realy realy efficent! i mean, unbelivable efficent. 
You get to concentrate at c++ if thats what you want, or to build up a nice 2d framework without having to spend lots of time with the most advance aspects of c++ programming.
instead of going with directX or OGL and having to bother with all of their optmization stuff and general knowledge SDL is a perfect way to go in my opinion.

You can from there move on to rather more "advaced" topics without so much headache.

Comment: I was considering using SDL, but than I heard it is pretty much a C based library. Looking deeper into that subject, I found the SFML, which is supposed to be a sort of SDL objected oriented clone. Is that correct? Would it be good to go to SFML?

Comment: Oh, SFML could be used aswell. But even if SDL i a C based Library, it dont stop you from using c++. C++ is built from C so it dont realy make any difference in my eyes. but here is where you have to make the big choise. pick one and go with it to the end.

Comment: SFML provides hardware acceleration out of the box, which SDL does not, unless you use OpenGL for drawing.

Comment: Does hardware acceleration matter on a sprite sheet based 2D game? I mean, aren't my game graphics just a bunch of images being load one at the time?

Comment: Well, Yes. Instead of having 8 pixels drawn per time ( cpu ), you have 200 pixels drawn ( gpu ). this makes things alot faster!